# Changes in AngularJS 1.3

Tags: angularjs

I've just started with AngularJS and I was going through a set of Hello World examples and I can't get them running on branch 1.3 of the the library.

**HTML code**

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
    <input ng-model='greeting.text'>
    <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**controller.js**

```
function HelloController($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
```

This works fine in 1.2.
I couldn't find the changes that have been made in 1.3 that cause this.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646941/getting-an-error-when-using-ng-controller-in-angularjs-ver-1-3-0/26647015#26647015

Comment: Okay that actually worked. Another thing - is it good to start with 1.3 as a beginner

Comment: :) yes i thinks so coz u dont need to hang with previous ones since u have the newest better ones , if u get conflict like this u can search for previous things and find a solution :)

Comment: Okay so I have to keep on annoying people here like this.. great. :)

Comment: lol happy learningg :)

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha put it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Angular 1.3 beta 15, $controller does not look for controllers anymore on window. [The AngularJS changelog explains in a clear manner what precisely has changed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-beta15-unbelievable-advancement-2014-07-11) (scroll to the 'Breaking Changes' section).