# Why is my ng-if not working? It's not hiding the div

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

In my Angular app, I want a certain `div` to appear if a variable is true, and to disappear if it is false.

However, it is not working. [See my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ow8emsh5/)

Can anyone help me understand why?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div id="newProjectButton" class="project" ng-click="newProjectActive()" ng-if="!creatingNew">
            <h1> + </h1>
            <h3> New Project </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="newProjectActive" class="project" ng-if="creatingNew">
        <form>
            <input name="name" ng-model="newProjectName" type="text"></input>
            <button ng-click="newProject()" type="submit" class='btn btn-primary'>Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.creatingNew = false;

    $scope.newProjectActive = function () {
        $scope.creatingNew = true;
    }

    $scope.newProject = function () {
        alert($scope.newProjectName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when I looked at your fiddle, there was older version of your example there,

Second, which actually may be a reason, is in that example you were using angular in version 1.0.1, and i believe that version didn't implement ng-if. Updating to latest version will fix your problem

Comment: @Imray my bad, i forgot version 1.3.0 was released, it works on 1.2.27, to find reason why it didn't work for you you need to find at differences between 1.2.x and 1.3.x, but that is different question. My Guess is it cant find controller as when you add `myApp.controller("MyCtrl",MyCtrl);` to end of script it works fine

Answer (score 5):

your angular version is `1.0.1`. directive `ng-if` is not in this version of angular.
its introduce in angular 1.1.5
check this [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2659-migrating-from-ui-if-to-ng-if-in-angularjs.htm)
 and
check it in angular under `Directives` topic [change log](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#115-triangle-squarification-2013-05-22)

```
AngularJS first added the ngIf directive in 1.1.5
```

please update the angular version

here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ow8emsh5/3/)

your controller should be like

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope) {
```

because the global controllers are not supported by default in angular 1.3... [check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646941/getting-an-error-when-using-ng-controller-in-angularjs-ver-1-3-0/26647015#26647015)

Comment: In my real project I'm actually using `AngularJS v1.3.4` and it's still not working

Comment: your controller should be like `myApp.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope) {`