# Can ng-if variable be modified inside a block that is using it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I'm finding this issue strange.

Basically I want a block to exist on a page based on an `ng-if` condition. But when I try to modify that `ng-if` inside said block, it doesn't have any effect on any other elements.

Why is this happening?

[The JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmyxs8qh/1/) and the code is below:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-init="shouldShow=false">
        <div ng-if="!shouldShow">
            <p>{{shouldShow}}</p>
            <div>
                <button ng-click="shouldShow=!shouldShow">Hide Section</button>
                <button ng-if="!shouldShow">Should Disappear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342106/why-is-my-ng-if-not-working-its-not-hiding-the-div/27342201#27342201. check the answer and this will solve your problem. :)

Comment: here is a simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/2f7Lynok/

Comment: @K.Toress updated the Angular version and still not working http://jsfiddle.net/hzxNa/364/

Comment: use `ng-hide` instead :)

Comment: @K.Toress In your JSFiddle, when I click the button, everything should disappear, since it's all contained in the `ng-if` div. But it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with `ng-if` child scope and the fact you are trying to 2-way bind a primitive in a child scope.

You should always try to use objects in your scope as `models` so that you leverage the benefits of prototypical inheritance.

See the difference here:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div >
        <p>{{model.shouldShow}}</p>
        <div ng-if="!model.shouldShow">
            <button ng-click="model.shouldShow=!model.shouldShow">Hide Section</button>
            <p>{{model.shouldShow}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.model={shouldShow:false}
}
```

Also read the docs for `ng-init`. It should not be used for arbitrary variables. It's main purpose is for aliasing variables in `ng-repeat`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hzxNa/365/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) explains what happens:

> Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed
>   and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope
>   created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal
>   inheritance. An important implication of this is if ngModel is used
>   within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent
>   scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the
>   child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

In short: Once you modify `shouldShow` in the child scope, it overrides the `shouldShow` of the parent scope (prototypical inheritance). As pointed out in another answer, this can be solved with an indirection via a shared object: `wrapperObject.shouldShow`. Unless you assign a new value to `wrapperObject` in the child scope it will point to the same instance as the parent scope (and therefore contain the same instance of `shouldShow`).