# Conditionals in angular templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently developping an app using ionic (1.3)/angular (1.5). This is my first time using angular, but I have been developping with ember.js for the past two or three years.

I'm a bit confused by how I can conditionally display stuff in templates : in ember, I would do

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  {{#if condition}}
    some template..
  {{else}}
    something else
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

But in angular, it seems to me that you'd have to do :

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="condition">
  some template..
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="!condition>
  something else
</div>
```

Which to me seems really cumbersome and does not really convey the intention. Is there any other (better) way to display stuff conditionally in templates ?

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates

Comment: thanks, didn't found the link when searching. Even if I did though, I'd have hoped that something cleaner would have been added in the three years since the answer...

Comment: ternary operator should be a nice practice.... depending on template size

Comment: @ksol Take a try with this one: https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-elif

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to achieve this as show in the code below:-

```
<div ng-switch="myVar">
  <div ng-switch-when="condition1">
     some tempelate....
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="condition2">
     some tempelate....
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="condition3">
     some tempelate....
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
     some fallback template ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this, here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/3179/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="condition">
  some template..
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="!condition">
  something else
</div>
</div>
```

controller, try using changing `$scope.condition=false`

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.condition = true;
   //$scope.condition = false;
 }
```

Comment: that's exactly the same as what I'm trying to avoid, expect instead of ng-if you use ng-show

Comment: I think `ng-show` is better for your conditional template. Because `ng-if` requires expression or condition, for more [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide). if you still want to use `ng-if` then check the version of angular. because `ng-if` is introduced in `version 1.1.5`. [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342106/why-is-my-ng-if-not-working-its-not-hiding-the-div)