# AngularJS simple ng-controller error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angularJS, `ng-app` works `ng-model` works, but when I try `ng-controller`, it does not work, the fault is on my side but I am unable to figure out what it is, I am not even trying anything fancy, just trying make the ng-controller work,

what is my mistake in the below code?

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="">
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
</div>`
```

and JS :

```
function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
    $scope.helloMessage="Hello World";
}
```

same problem when run in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohk3xm37/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646941/getting-an-error-when-using-ng-controller-in-angularjs-ver-1-3-0/26647015#26647015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('HelloWorldCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.helloMessage = "Hello world";

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
</div>
```