# AngularJS Beginner is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app>

    <div ng-controller="DatumCtrl">
        <p>{{datum}}</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js:

```
var DatumCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.datum = new Date();
};
```

With this I get an error:

"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DatumCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.

I have copied tis code from an introductory articel on AngularJS and have no prior experience with AngularJS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646941/getting-an-error-when-using-ng-controller-in-angularjs-ver-1-3-0/26647015#26647015 this may helps you

Comment: Seems you have almost nothing in your code, did you follow any angular tutorial ?

Comment: Since angular v1.3 you can't have global controllers. So I guess you downloaded the latest angular-version but your tutorial uses some 1.2.x version where your code would work just fine. Tip: Drop that tutorial and find an *up-to-date* one.

Answer (score 2):

To have the controller you need to have the module first:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
```

And use :  `ng-app="MyApp"`

Answer (score 1):

This code example goes from Controller Basics Tutorial by Scot Allen and it will throw exception like

> "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got
>   undefined

So the reason of this that since v1.3 you can't have global controllers

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.6" data-semver="1.3.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>{{ 55 * 2}}</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1> {{message}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

script.js before v1.3

```
var MainController = function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello I am Angular";
};
```

script.js after v1.3

```
angular.module('controllerExample', [])
  .controller('MainController', ['$scope', MainController]);

function MainController($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello I am Angular";
}
```

and in your index.html

```
<html ng-app="controllerExample">
```

[see Plunker with solved example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7Ov5H927lAehd70Xttq?p=info)