# why ng-controller is not calling or working or function is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Script/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
```

// controller defined //

```
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="data in customers">
```

// data is not access controller

```
             {{data.name}}-{{data.city}}
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

/*Is this way is correct to define controller*/

```
    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope) {
                 $scope.customers = [
                 { name: 'alok ', city: 'azam' },
                 { name: 'muku', city: 'lko' },
                 { name: 'rajat', city: 'jungle' }

                 ];}
                 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: angularjs version ? if its 1.3 or above please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646941/getting-an-error-when-using-ng-controller-in-angularjs-ver-1-3-0/26647015#26647015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten your html a bit and it works now. 
You have to define module called myApp and have to use controller directive to define controller in the module.
Please look at the sample I've added
http://jsfiddle.net/uv0gw4kL/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SimpleController">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in customers">
      {{data.name}}-{{data.city}}
  </li>
</ul>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
            { name: 'alok ', city: 'azam' },
            { name: 'muku', city: 'lko' },
            { name: 'rajat', city: 'jungle' }
            ];
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

More about angular controllers here
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

You can also use allowGlobals feature from controller provider
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider
but it's not recommended.